# Operations on nested dicts and lists

Tags: python

I have file containing test results in the following format:

```
TEST1=passed
TEST2=failed
TEST3=passed
```

I want to compare the tests with it's scope:

```
test_scope = {
    'SCOPE1': [
        'TEST1',
        'TEST2',
    ],
    'SCOPE2': [
        'TEST3',
    ],
    'SCOPE3': [
        'TEST4',
        'TEST5',
    ],
    'SCOPE4': [
        'TEST6',
        'TEST7',
    ],
}
```

The ideal output would be:

```
test_results = {
    "SCOPE1": [
        {
            "name": "TEST1", 
            "result": "passed"
            "id": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "TEST2", 
            "result": "failed"
            "id": 1
        },
    ],
    "SCOPE2": [
        {
            "name": "TEST3", 
            "result": "passed"
            "id": 1
        },
    ],
    "SCOPE3": [
        {
            "name": "TEST4", 
            "result": "not run"
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "TEST5", 
            "result": "not run"
            "id": 1
        },
    ]
    "SCOPE4": [
        {
            "name": "TEST6", 
            "result": "not run"
            "id": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "TEST7", 
            "result": "not run"
            "id": 1
        },
    ],
}
```

where `id` is the testname index in the list in `test_scope`.

What I have achieved:

```
class TBD(object):
   def get_test_results(self, path, results_file):
        test_results = []
        with open('path', 'r') as results_file:
            lines = results_file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                test_case = line.rstrip().split('=')[0]
                test_result = line.rstrip().split('=')[1]
                for section, tests in test_scope.iteritems():
                    if test_case in tests:
                        section = section
                        id = tests.index(test_case)
                        test_results.append({'name': test_case,
                                             'result': test_result,
                                             'section': section,
                                             'id': id)
        return test_results
```

With output:

```
[{'id': 0, 
  'section': 'SCOPE1', 
  'name': 'TEST1', 
  'result': 'passed'},
...]
```

However I am stuck and don't know how to get the test cases with **not run** results (those present in `test_scope` but not in `test_results`).

Any advice on how to progress from here?  Of course the data structure can be freely changed if there is easier way to store it, as I am quite inexperienced yet :)

Comment: How are those ids mapped? Because your inputs, `tc1`, `tc2`, etc. seem to have no relationship to the data in the `test_scope` data structure. Your code says the names should match those in the list.

Comment: If you need to output all `test_scope` entries, then parse your input file into a dictionary (mapping test name to outcome), and use that when looping over the scopes to determine a) if the test ran, and b) what the outcome was. (`test_result = test_cases.get(test_name, '<did not run>')`).

Comment: My mistake. Already corrected. TEST1=pass matches test_case and test_result (i.e TEST1, passed). Still no idea why ASAP degrade the question... Will check your soultion.

Comment: dictionary keys have to be unique. I see two keys `SCOPE3`. values are not required to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than drive your output by the test results file, split reading the test results and outputting your `test_results` data structure into two separate steps.

In step one, read the file, and store the information into a dictionary mapping test name -> result. In step two, produce the `test_results` output by walking the `test_scope` data structure, using the dictionary produced by step 1 to determine test outcomes. This makes it trivial to include *all* entries from `test_scope`, even if the test was not part of the test run.

```
# step 1, read the results file
results = {}
with open('path', 'r') as results_file:
    results = dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in results_file if line.strip())

# step 2, build the output
test_results = {
    scope: [
        {
            "id": i,
            "name": test_name,
            "result": results.get(test_name, "not run"),
        } for i, test_name in enumerate(tests)
    ] for scope, tests in test_scope.iteritems()
}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> results_file_data = '''\
... TEST1=passed
... TEST2=failed
... TEST3=passed
... '''
>>> with BytesIO(results_file_data) as results_file:
...     results = dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in results_file if line.strip())
...
>>> test_results = {
...     scope: [
...         {
...             "id": i,
...             "name": test_name,
...             "result": results.get(test_name, "not run"),
...         } for i, test_name in enumerate(tests)
...     ] for scope, tests in test_scope.iteritems()
... }
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(test_results)
{'SCOPE1': [{'id': 0, 'name': 'TEST1', 'result': 'passed'},
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'TEST2', 'result': 'failed'}],
 'SCOPE2': [{'id': 0, 'name': 'TEST3', 'result': 'passed'}],
 'SCOPE3': [{'id': 0, 'name': 'TEST4', 'result': 'not run'},
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'TEST5', 'result': 'not run'}],
 'SCOPE4': [{'id': 0, 'name': 'TEST6', 'result': 'not run'},
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'TEST7', 'result': 'not run'}]}
```